# Are there any sailboating rules in additional to COLREGS?

Tags: safety, sailing

I had a sailing test a few weeks ago and in it I was presented with the B flag and was asked what it means and what would be the applicable light at night.

I know the answer is "carrying dangerous substances and the light is an all-round red light" but I can't find where this is defined to make sure I'm not missing other rules not in COLREGs ([Collision Regulations](http://www.bosunsmate.org/seamanship/rulesoftheroad.php)).

Are there any additional international rules for boating lights and signals apart from the [COLREG Navigation Light and Signal Flag Rules](http://working-the-sails.com/lights_flags_and_signals.html)?

Answer (score 6):

While there are country specific regulations which may apply close to shore or on inland waterways, the international community agrees that the COLREGs form the basis for rules, so as long as you know them you will be at least on the right side of the law.

The standard for lights is the same the world over and while you may have some specific rules when racing, for example, this should not change the COLREG guidance.